# Linux hidden files & Grep

Tags: linux, grep

Grep shows hidden files not seen otherwise.  Listing the files in a folder(on a Redhat server) using "ls -a" yields no results for specific hidden files(even as root user).  However, if I use "ls -a | grep {pattern}" on the same folder those hidden files are listed. The files are recognized names, owned by normal users/groups, and with non-zero file sizes.  Note: These files can be moved/renamed and deleted.

Question:  What might cause this to occur?

Comment: Possibly there are unprintable characters in the filenames.  But more details are needed.  Show the output of your commands.  Pipe the result of grep to xxd.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I considered the possibility of unprintable characters, but dismissed that when file deletion did not require quotes.  I’ll pipe the results through xxd at the next opportunity, unfortunately the current files had to be removed. (they prevented reports from running properly)